# How to Serve a React App with Django on Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: node.js, django, reactjs, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I used to have my app on Heroku and the way it worked there was that I had 2 buildpacks. One for NodeJS and one for Python. Heroku ran `npm run build` and then Django served the files from the `build` folder.

I use Code Pipeline on AWS to deploy a new version of my app every time there is a new push on my GitHub repository.

Since I couldn't figure out how to run `npm run build` in a python environment in EB, I had a workaround. I ran `npm run build` and pushed it to my repository (removed the `build` folder from .gitignore) and then Django served the files on EB.

However, this is not the best solution and I was wondering if anyone knows how to run `npm run build` the way Heroku can do it with their NodeJS buildpack for a python app on EB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I figured out one solution that worked for me.

Since I want to create the build version of my app on the server the way Heroku does it with the NodeJS buildpack, I had to create a command that installs node like this:

```
container_commands:
  01_install_node:
    command: "curl -sL https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | sudo bash - && sudo yum install nodejs"
    ignoreErrors: false
```

And then to create the build version of the react app on a Python Environment EB, I added the following command:

```
container_commands:
  02_react:
    command: "npm install && npm run build"
    ignoreErrors: false
```

So of course, after the build version is created, you should collect static files, so here is how my working config file looked at the end:

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
    WSGIPath: <project_name>/wsgi.py

  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: <project_name>.settings

  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:staticfiles:
    /static/: staticfiles/

container_commands:
  01_install_node:
    command: "curl -sL https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | sudo bash - && sudo yum install nodejs"
    ignoreErrors: false

  02_react:
    command: "npm install && npm run build"
    ignoreErrors: false

  03_collectstatic:
    command: "django-admin.py collectstatic --noinput"
```

Hope this helps anyone who encounters the same

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly Python but I guess you can adapt for you case.

Elastic Beanstalk for Node.js platform use by default `app.js`, then `server.js`, and then `npm start` (in that order) to start your application.

You can change this behavior with **configuration files**. Below the steps to accomplish with Node.js:

1. Create the following file `.ebextensions/<your-config-file-name>.config` with the following content:

   ```
   option_settings:
     aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:nodejs:
       NodeCommand: "npm run eb:prod"
   ```
2. Edit your `package.json` to create the `eb:prod` command. For instance:

   ```
   "scripts": {
     "start": "razzle start",
     "build": "razzle build",
     "test": "razzle test --env=jsdom",
     "start:prod": "NODE_ENV=production node build/server.js",
     "eb:prod": "npm run build && npm run start:prod"
   }
   ```
3. You may faced permission denied errors during your build. To solve this problem you can create `.npmrc` file with the following content:

   ```
   # Force npm to run node-gyp also as root
   unsafe-perm=true
   ```

If you need more details, I wrote a blogpost about it: [I deployed a server-side React app with AWS Elastic Beanstalk. Here’s what I learned.](https://medium.com/@johanrin/i-deployed-a-server-side-react-app-with-aws-elastic-beanstalk-heres-what-i-learned-34c8399079c5?source=friends_link&sk=6e05dee451fe68f3b290ff70c582bfb5)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I use Python for not only serving the react app but for the API and authentication. And in order to use Python and the Django framework, I have to use EB for Python. So I was wondering if it is possible to build the production version of my react app in my pythonic EB.

Comment: I cannot help you about python but the concept is still the same. You have to customize the command with `.ebextensions` to start your application. To give you an idea of how edit your config file: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html#python-django-configure-for-eb