# How to Deploy Django Serving React App on AWS Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: reactjs, django, amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

After quite a bit of debugging, I finally managed to successfully deploy the Django portion of my full-stack app on AWS Elastic Beanstalk. Here is the .config file in .ebextensions that I'm using:

```
option_settings:
    aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
        DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: "waifu_database.settings"
        PYTHONPATH: "/opt/python/current/app/waifu_database:$PYTHONPATH"

    aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
        WSGIPath: waifu_database.wsgi:application
```

However, I still have the React portion to deploy. I know that it would probably be easier to separate the two, but is there a way I can install all the packages using npm and deploy it with the Django backend? I've already tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61270154/how-to-serve-a-react-app-with-django-on-elastic-beanstalk)
but it just gave me a "Failed to deploy application" error. Here is my file directory:

```
waifu_database
|- .ebextensions
|- .elasticbeanstalk
|- api
|- frontend
  |- node_modules/
  |- src/
  |- static/
  |- templates/
  |- package.json
|- waifu_database
  |- asgi.py
  |- settings.py
  |- urls.py
  |- wsgi.py
|- manage.py
|- requirements.txt
```

Here is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "webpack --mode production --watch",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.19.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.19.3",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.5",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "webpack": "^5.74.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.18.6",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.4.2"
  }
}
```