# Django + React : How to connect them for deployment?

Tags: django, reactjs, production

I am running an app with `Django+DRF`, `CELERY+REDIS` ,`ReactJs+REDUX` & `JWT`, and i am having a hard time connecting `backend` with the `frontend` for deployment.

i have used `create-react-app` to generate React code; and `npm run build` to generate the production build.

i have been looking around but i can't find a tutorial on how to link them together.

if you guys have any link in your pocket that i can follow i'll be thankful to you.

Comment: for production build or for development?

Comment: production build, the app is finished.

Comment: @NONAMA i have an issue with moving the files into django

Comment: i'll follow this guide, it seems like this programmer had the same issue as me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53517329/deploying-seprate-react-frontend-and-django-drf-api?rq=1

Comment: I read answers and for me it seems good. I wanted to suggest the similar solution. My version in the answer below.

Comment: all set mate !!!

Comment: @NONAMA yes share it mate !

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to move your React files "into" Django. Just serve them separately.

This is how I serve my projects:

[image]

I serve my API from `/api/` url, so here's a rough representation of my Nginx config:

```conf
server {

    # urls that start with /api or /admin
    location ~ ^/(api|admin) {
        # pass them to uwsgi or gunicorn
        ...
    }

    # urls that start with /media
    location /media  {
        # serve from your project's media folder
        ...
    }

    # urls that start with /static/admin 
    location /static/admin {
        # these requests are made to admin's static files
        # serve them from your staticroot folder
        # i.e. where your files are stored after you run `collectstatic`
        ...
    }

    # everything else
    location / {
        # serve from frontend build folder
        root   /path/to/the/build/folder;
        index  index.html;
        # this is important
        # first try to find files matching url, like css, or js, or favicon
        # if nothing found, serve the index.html            
        try_files $uri /index.html; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Dear xyres, which hosting company did you use?
Did you use docker compose?
I want to deploy my django app  and react app but decoupled.

Comment: @Lobbel Any hosting service which gives you a virtual server: Digital Ocean, AWS, Vultr etc. I don't use Docker (yeah I know, still working like a caveman). I ssh into the server, then install nginx, databases and anything else that's required. Then I pull my code from github and start the application server. I would like to learn docker, though.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned in comments, this solution seems reasonble for me.

[Deploying Seprate React Frontend and Django DRF API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53517329/deploying-seprate-react-frontend-and-django-drf-api?rq=1)

In your case as I understood you can start your DEV version of Django+DRF on the random port, like localhost:5000/. Then you can start DEV server on create-react-app on the other port, like localhost:8080/. For testing purposes you can check connections between frontend and backend, using DRF urls in React app.

After that, you can build your React app and add bundle.js as a standard js file to your index.html in Django project.
Create 'home' url in django and connect it with the simple template such you're using in index.html in React app.

Your bundle.js will include all necessary libriaries. But for production version on the server you will need to build your app once again for actual urls with actual domain.

Hope it helps.