# Setting up deployment for Django+React project having each run on different ports with Nginx

Tags: django, reactjs, nginx, web-deployment

I am developing a **Django** `(for Web API serving)` + **React** `(frontend purpose)` project where the codebase for both Django and React are consolidated in a main project folder, meaning both are on the same git repository, as below:

```
.  
+-- _backend  
|   +-- _config
|   |   +-- settings.py
|   |   +-- urls.py
|   |   +-- wsgi.py
|   +-- _sample_app
|   +-- _static
|   +-- _media
|   +-- manage.py
|   +-- requirements.txt
+-- _frontend
|   +-- _public
|   +-- _src
|   |   +-- App.css
|   |   +-- App.js
|   |   +-- index.js
|   +-- babel.rc
|   +-- package-lock.json
|   +-- package.json
|   +-- webpack.config.js
```

Now, I would like to implement the recommended way of integrating both technologies:

1. Django as a `standalone backend app` that only serves API (no UI, assets, templates)
2. React as a `standalone SPA` whose purpose is to serve the frontend (UI, web pages, assets, etc.)

Which means that Django will be starting on its own port and React also on its own. Now, during development I could do:

1. React on `localhost:3000`
2. Django on `localhost:3001`

However, I am not pretty sure how to deploy using the above setup on production server. I will be using `Nginx` for this project.

Comment: Why does React need a separate port? For production, you're supposed to create a build which you can use just like a regular Javascript resource. I answered a similar question some time ago about Django and React SPA: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60706686/1925257

Comment: Cool, thanks a lot! Also, if you're interested maybe you'd like to check this small project I've made [https://github.com/michaeljarizala/django-react-app-boilerplate](https://github.com/michaeljarizala/django-react-app-boilerplate). I'm gathering reviews for this project for further improvements. Thanks!