# Host Django and React on the same server?

Tags: reactjs, django, nginx, deployment, server

I am working on a SAS product. So there could be 1000 users using my application at the same time.

**Technologies Used:**

- Django for Backend
- React.js for frontend
- Django Rest Framework for APIs

I have hosted this project on a server with customized Nginx settings as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60706686/6476015

For now, I am having no issues but I want to know if there is some possibility of something going wrong in the future as usage and data will increase. Should I host the frontend and backend on separate servers?

Comment: Take a look at this tutorial https://saasitive.com/tutorial/docker-compose-django-react-nginx-let-s-encrypt/

Comment: Hi Kamal, i have the same setup as you, django and react decoupled.
How did you manage to deploy them?
Which hosting company do you use?